# Schedule iOS background tasks as of iOS 13

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13

I am implementing BackgroundTasks Framework for updating the data. But I got the below issue

> Could not schedule refreshApp: Error Domain=BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
> Could not schedule data featch: Error Domain=BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
> 2019-10-01 19:19:32.550320+0530 SOBackgroundTask[34131:1129470] Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 3 (0x3), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The solution is to run on a device. I was running on a simulator. However, It was showing the Background App Refresh has been enabled in Settings while running on the simulator.

There may be some other reasons. Please visit
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskschedulererrorcode/bgtaskschedulererrorcodeunavailable?language=objc

Answer (score 43):

Here are possible error codes for `Domain=BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain` extracted from ObjC headers with some explanation.

`BGTaskSchedulerErrorCodeUnavailable = 1` // Background task scheduling functionality is not available for this app/extension. Background App Refresh may have been disabled in Settings.

`BGTaskSchedulerErrorCodeTooManyPendingTaskRequests = 2` // The task request could not be submitted because there are too many pending task requests of this type. Cancel some existing task requests before trying again.

`BGTaskSchedulerErrorCodeNotPermitted = 3` // The task request could not be submitted because the appropriate background mode is not included in the UIBackgroundModes array, or its identifier was not present in the BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers array in the app's Info.plist.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskschedulererrorcode?language=objc

Answer (score 9):

For:

```
BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain error 3
```

Check inside the project’s `.xcodeproj` file for the appropriate target. Then go to the info tab and **Custom iOS Target Properties** and check that the permitted background task scheduler identifiers (`BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers`) are added.

This solved my problem when adding `BackgroundTasks` to an existing project.

Comment: Just want to add that for it to work best you should use the "com.COMPANY.IDNAME" format for your identifiers

Answer (score 4):

Please check if you miss registering `BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers` in info.plist file of your project.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested on real device(iOS13.2, and iOS13.2.2), but it's same result.

Error Domain=BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)"
Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 37 (0x25), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.

Error Domain=BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 113 (0x71), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.

It seems that there is still exist bug.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121990

Comment: When I run debug command schedule is successful but I get the same error (Code 1) on real device when its scheduling a task. (iOS 13.2.3)

Comment: @Teo what did you mean? succeeded on simulator? and failed on real device?

Comment: This has been fixed in iOS 13.4 GM.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because that your mobile turn the bg refresh off!!!!!!!

Comment: man you made my day even though I was searching for another question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: how to turn on bg refresh off , iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

In case of BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain error 3, I didn't add below

````
<array>
    <string>com.shiny.job</string>
    <string>com.shiny.jobpower</string>
    <string>com.shiny.jobnet</string>
    <string>com.shiny.jobpowernet</string>
</array>```
````

Comment: Didn't add them to where?

Answer (score 0):

Just check the Background Modes has been added to the target Capabilities and that Background fetch and Background processing options are selected

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskschedulererrorcode/bgtaskschedulererrorcodeunavailable?language=objc, this error usually occurs for one of three reasons:

- The user has disabled background refresh in settings.
- The app is running on Simulator which doesn’t support background
  processing.
- The keyboard extension either hasn’t set RequestsOpenAccess to YES in
  The Info.plist File, or the user hasn’t granted open access.
- The extension type isn’t able to schedule background tasks.

Answer (score 0):

check you Appdelegate.swift is including WorkmanagerPlugin.registerTask(withIdentifier: "your.task.id")

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Task Identifier entered in the info.plist matches the one that you're using. I could've sworn I had them matching but I didn't, which elicited the error above.
Note the mismatch below:

[image: Picture of info.plist showing the 2 task identifier strings, one saying com.example.briefTask, and one saying com.example.extendedTask]

[image: Picture of Swift code showing a BGTask being registered with the task identifier com.example.MyExtendedTask]